# precision of double function based string

Tags: c++

Let's say that you have a function:

```
string function(){
double f = 2.48452
double g = 2
double h = 5482.48552
double i = -78.00
double j = 2.10
return x; // ***
}
```

*** for x we insert:

```
if we will insert f, function returns: 2.48
if we will insert g, function returns: 2
if we will insert h, function returns: 5482.49
if we will insert i, function returns:-78
if we will insert j, function returns: 2.1
```

They are only example, who shows how the funcion() works. To precise: 
The function for double k return rounded it to: k.XX, 
but for:
k=2.20
it return 2.2 as string.
How it implements?

Comment: [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)?

Comment: This isn't really a site where you say what code you want written then wait for someone to write it for you.  There are so many problems with your code I dont know where to begin.  Go get an education.

Comment: Is string `std::string`? As that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Just because you see two digits, it doesn't mean the underlying value was necessarily *rounded* to two digits.

The precision of the *VALUE* and the number of digits displayed in the *FORMATTED OUTPUT* are two completely different things.

2) If you're using cout, you can control formatting with "setprecision()":

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

EXAMPLE (from the above link):

```
// setprecision example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::fixed
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

int main () {
  double f =3.14159;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

sample output:

```
3.1416
3.14159
3.14159
3.141590000
```

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, `2.2` is exactly the same as `2.20`, `2.200`, `2.2000`, and so on. If you want to see more insignificant zeros, use `[setprecision][1]`:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
cout << 2.2 << endl; // Prints 2.20
```

Answer (score 0):

To show up to 2 decimal places, but not showing trailing zeros you can do something such as:

```
std::string function(double value)
{
  // get fractional part
  double fracpart = value - static_cast<long>(value);

  // compute fractional part rounded to 2 decimal places as an int
  int decimal  = static_cast<int>(100*fabs(fracpart) + 0.5);
  if (decimal >= 100) decimal -= 100;

  // adjust precision based on the number of trailing zeros
  int precision = 2; // default 2 digits precision
  if      (0 ==  decimal)       precision = 0; // 2 trailing zeros, don't show decimals
  else if (0 == (decimal % 10)) precision = 1; // 1 trailing zero, keep 1 decimal place

  // convert value to string
  std::stringstream str;
  str << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << value;
  return str.str();
}
```